# Python If else Statment issue

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create an RSI indicator in excel using Python. I was able to create columns in the CSV file that was downloaded by Pandas datareader. However, I need to create a column for upward movement and downward movement where if there was a price increase greater than 0 than previous closing price then it should populate that difference else 0. I am not able to get that. Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
if msft_df['Gains/Loss'] > 0:
    msft_df['Upward Movement'] = msft_df['Gains/Loss']
else:
    msft_df['Upward Movement'] = 0
```

Comment: What's supposed to happen if `msft_df['Gains/Loss']` has a mix of negative and positive values?  `if/else` statements don't iterate!

Comment: If Gains/Loss is a positive number, Upward movement should be equal to 'Gains/Loss' else it should be 0. If there is another way to do it, please feel free to suggest it. Thank you!

Comment: `msft_df['Gains/Loss']` isn't one number; it's a Series.